# How to left align the \dcase to make a straight margin with text

Tags: equations, align, cases

I am using `dcase` to express my equation. However, the equation looks align in center of page. I want to move the equation in the left side of the page. Note that, my text has one space at the beginning of paragraph

[image]

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt, sort&compress]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{amsmath,math tools}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{dcases}
u_j^{k+1}(x)=
  \!\begin{multlined}[t]
  \argmin_{u}
  \biggl\{
  \frac{\mu}{2}\int\limits_{\Omega} (u_j(x)-m(x))^2\diff x \biggr\},
  \end{multlined}
\\[1ex]
f'(x_{0})=0 : z=f(x_{0}) \text{ is de horizontale raaklijn.}
\\[1ex]
\lim_{x\to x_{0}} f'(x)=\pm\infty : x=x_{0} \text{ is de verticale raaklijn.}
\\[1ex]
g(x_{0}){R}_{0} : z-f(x_{0})=f'(x_{0})\cdot(x-x_{0})
  \text{ is de raaklijn.}
\end{dcases}
\end{equation}

This is text. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Then don't use `equation` use `flalign` from `amsmath` with `&&` after `\end{dcases}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
\begin{dcases}
u_j^{k+1}(x)=
  \argmin_{u}
  \biggl\{
  \frac{\mu}{2}\int_{\Omega} (u_j(x)-m(x))^2\diff x \biggr\},
                                \\[1ex]
f'(x_{0})=0 : z=f(x_{0}) \text{ is de horizontale raaklijn.}
                                \\[1ex]
\lim_{x\to x_{0}} f'(x)=\pm\infty : x=x_{0} \text{ is de verticale raaklijn.}
                                \\[1ex]
g(x_{0}){R}_{0} : z-f(x_{0})=f'(x_{0})\cdot(x-x_{0})
  \text{ is de raaklijn.}
\end{dcases}&&&
\end{flalign}

This is text.
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** You can also use `equation` environment and before `dcases` add \hspace{-}. However, `<dsired shift>` can be determined by trial and errors ... This at `flalign` environment is not needed. There equation start at left text border. Of course, in real aplication you had to omit package `showframe`.

I also corect the MWE according to comment of Barbara Beeton and Mico.

Comment: It is right. However, is it possible to use \equation in that problem?

Comment: i may be missing something, but i don't think `multlined` is needed in the first line of the braced display.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, I overlook this in OP code. of Course it is surplus. I will erase it.

Comment: In my opinion, `\int\limits_{\Omega}` makes the resulting expression too tall. `\int_{\Omega}` would seem to generate better-proportioned output.

Comment: It only for a big height equation. I used flalign. It worked well. But I still regards a way which use \equation

Comment: @user8430, you use equation and you wasn't satisfied with result. Since you already have `mathtools` in preamble, why you not use ther math environments?

Comment: Thank you. It is not affect to citation/reference in text, is it right. I still use \eqref{eq:1} for above equation (assume i label it is 1)

Comment: @user8430, referencing in all amsmath environments is the same as at  `equation`.

Comment: Thanks. I used it in text. It can refer to the equation. However, in appendix (no equation number), it does not refer. I used the option  \begin{flalign*}  \end{flalign*}